# Expo Location not working on android device

Tags: android, typescript, expo

I am stuck with a problem on my android device. The function `getCurrentPositionAsync` and `watchPositionAsync` work fine on my iOS device, android emulator and also on android simulator launched via Expo Go but does not work in my android device after I create an apk or aab via `expo build:android`

Here is the simplified component accessing location:
**availability-box-android.component.tsx**

```
const AvailabilityBoxAndroid = () => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const [locationErrorMessage, setLocationErrorMessage] = useState<String>('');
    const [androidLocation, setAndroidLocation] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const states: StandardButtonStates = {
          on: {
            isActive: isLocationServicesAvailable && adHocAvailabilityStatus,
            appearance: 'ghost',
            onPress: handleAdHocAvailabilityButtonPressOff,
            text: t('Set unavailable'),
          },
          off: {
            isActive: isLocationServicesAvailable && !adHocAvailabilityStatus,
            appearance: 'ghost',
            onPress: handleAdHocAvailabilityButtonPressOn,
            text: t('Set available'),
          },
          disabled: {
            isActive: !isLocationServicesAvailable,
            text: t('Set available (Location disabled)'),
          },
        };
  }, [
    androidLocation,
  ]);

    const handleAdHocAvailabilityButtonPressOn = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        let { status } = await ExpoLocation.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setLocationErrorMessage('Permission to access location was denied');
          return;
        }
        let location = await ExpoLocation.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setAndroidLocation(location);
        }};
    
    const handleAdHocAvailabilityButtonPressOff = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setAndroidLocation(null);
        return;
  };
  
    return (
        <ContentBox
          Title={
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignContent: 'stretch',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    height: 18,
                    width: 18,
                    backgroundColor: adHocAvailabilityStatus ? 'green' : 'red',
                    borderRadius: 18 / 2,
                  }}
                ></View>
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10, textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>
                  {adHocAvailabilityStatus ? t('available') + '' : t('unavailable') + ''}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <LocationIcon
                  active={locationForegroundPermissionResponse?.granted === true}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: 'Lato_700Bold',
                    marginLeft: 15,
                  }}
                >
                  {locationName ? locationName + '' : 'Location not known'}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          }
          Content={
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <StandardButton
                states={adHocAvailabilityButtonStates}
                isLoading={isLoading}
              ></StandardButton>
              {<Text>{JSON.stringify(androidLocation)}</Text>}
              <Text>{locationErrorMessage + ''}</Text>
            </View>
          }
        ></ContentBox>
      );
};
```

I tried creating a fresh project with just location and it worked so I am assuming it might be something with my conflicting libraries.
**package json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.21",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/dev": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/lato": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~0.12.63",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "@types/javascript-time-ago": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.171",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.27.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "expo": "^42.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.3.1",
    "expo-battery": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~3.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-localization": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-location": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.12.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-random": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-task-manager": "~9.2.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~9.2.0",
    "fingerprintjs2": "^2.1.4",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "javascript-time-ago": "^2.3.7",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-advertising-id": "^1.0.11",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1264.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@expo/ngrok": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.13.5",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: i have the same issue. did you find the problem?

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?